# Bash - Prompt for uid, loop user until valid input is entered, verify against all uid's in /etc/passwd

Tags: bash

Here is what I've been asked to do:

- Write a script to prompt a user for a valid uid.  Verify the following in your script and keep prompting the user till they give valid input (use a loop).  Show me your script and it working, ie you doing a few tests.  The following requirements should be met and tested in your feedback:

  1. number less than 65537
  2. number is more than 1000
  3. Verify against all uids from /etc/passwd and ensure it isn’t already in use.

I'm not sure what he means by numbers less than 65537 or number more than 1000 but this is what i have thus far.

```
#!bin/bash
read -p "Enter a username: " uname
users=`awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort`
while [[ -z "$uname ]]; do
    echo""
    echo "Error: Must supply a username!"
    echo ""
    read -p "Enter a username: " uname
    echo ""
for user in $users; do
    if [[ "$user" == "$uname" ]]; then
             echo "$uname exists"
             break
    else
             echo "doen't exist"
    fi
done
for user in $users; do
        if [[ "$user" == "$uname" ]]; then
                echo "$uname exists"
                exit
        else
                echo "doesn't exist"
                exit
        fi
done
```

Obviously im ridiculously new to this so any help would be incredible

Comment: *grumbles about unrealistic assignments* -- in the Real World, a best-practices approach would be doing a lookup by UID in a way that honors `/etc/nsswitch.conf` -- so if your UIDs were coming from NIS, or LDAP, or Active Directory, or otherwise something that isn't `/etc/passwd` you'd still get a useful result.

Comment: Anyhow -- note that the assignment is for you to ask the user for a **uid**, not for a **username**. Those are two very different things. While usernames are of course strings, UIDs are numbers.

Comment: UIDs are the **second** field in `/etc/passwd`, not the first one.

Comment: BTW, you should probably fix your unmatched quotes -- `[[ -z "$uname ]]` needs to be `[[ -z "$uname" ]]`, or just `[[ -z $uname ]]` since string-splitting and glob-expansion are implicitly disabled inside `[[ ]]`.

Comment: BTW -- in `#!/bin/bash`, it's proper to have the leading `/` -- thus `/bin`, not just `bin`.

Comment: (In general, by the way -- we ask that questions surrounding bugs in code center around an isolated question focusing on how that code fails, with both an exact error message and a [mcve] letting others reproduce the failure. I answered it since you had a code sample showing in a fair bit of detail what you were trying, which is appreciated -- but at this level of effort, the responses you get from StackOverflow are liable to be... uneven).

Comment: Thank you.changed print $1 to print $2 and now working through "unexpected end of file" error and figuring out the whole numbers less than / more than part.

Comment: I was actually wrong about UID being second -- it's the third. (Second field is password hashes on ancient systems, or a character indicating whether the account is enabled in modern ones, where the password hashes are moved to /etc/shadow). Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate you building your own answer (which is particularly a good idea if this is homework as StackOverflow Q&A entries are public record and searchable) -- but re: the numeric comparisons, I'm inclined to suggest that my answer is likely to be helpful there. (If it's not showing up, you might refresh the page?)

Comment: understood thank you for your time

Comment: @BlaqOut you haven't selected a correct answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
until (( uid < 65537 )) && (( uid > 1000 )) && ! getent -s files passwd $uid > /dev/null
do
    read -p "Enter a UID: " uid
    if(( uid > 65537 )) || (( uid < 1000 )); then
        echo "UID must be within 1001 - 65536" >&2
    elif getent -s files passwd $uid > /dev/null; then
        echo "UID $uid is already in use" >&2
    fi
done
```

Although your question specified `/etc/passwd` file, it is recommended to use the `getent` utility. By adding `-s files` option, it tells `getent` to read from the `files` backed passwd.

Comment: wouldn't `(( uid > 1000 && uid < 65537 )) && ! getent -s files passwd $uid >&-; do` suffice?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a uids_in_use=( )
while IFS=: read -r _ _ file_uid _; do
  (( f )) && uids_in_use[$file_uid]=1 ||:
done </etc/passwd

while read -r -p "Enter a UID:" entered_uid; do      
  if (( entered_uid < 1000 )); then
    echo "UIDs below 1000 are reserved for system use!" >&2
    continue
  fi
  if (( entered_uid > 65536 )); then
    echo "Maximum UID value is 65536!" >&2
    continue
  fi
  if [[ ${uids_in_use[$entered_uid]} ]]; then
    echo "UID $entered_uid is already in use!" >&2
    continue
  fi
  echo "UID $entered_uid is acceptable!"
  break
done
```

---

Items of note:

- The best-practice way to read a file is with a `while read` loop, as documented in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). In this particular case, `IFS=: read -r _ _ uid _` reads the third field of a line into the variable `uid`, discarding the first, second, and the set of all subsequent fields by assigning their results to the placeholder variable `_`.
- See in particular [Why You Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), regarding `for user in $users` being bad practice. (This expands globs -- thus replacing an entry of `*` with a list , ignores quoting and escaping in splitting on whitespace or other characters in IFS, etc)
- UIDs are numbers associated with each username. The assignment asks you to find a valid, unused UID -- **not** an unused username.
- `(( ))` creates an arithmetic context. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr -- inside this context, C-style syntax is available for integer math. (For other situations when you need floating-point math, see [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022)).
- `declare -a` declares a numerically-indexed array. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays, and [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005). Arrays in bash are sparse -- that is to say, you can assign to element 1000 without having 999 other elements before it, which is a property we make use of here. `array[$idx]=value` assigns to an array element, whereas `"${array[$idx]}"` performs a lookup.

Comment: Not a fan of `while :`, as it's a practice that can prove harmful in production.  In this case, there's a sleep while we wait for user input, but when that doesn't happen you can start consuming resources rapidly.

Comment: @SaintHax, good point. Moved that into the conditional so the loop terminates on EOF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this

```
# validate the new uid is in the usable range or error
valid_range() {
   local uid="$1"

   if [[ $uid -lt 65537 && $uid -gt 1000 ]]; then
      return 0
   else
      echo "Invalid range" >&2
      return 1
   fi
}

# make sure the uid is not in use
unused() {
   local uid="$1"

   awk -F: -v u=$uid '{if ($3 == u){print "Uid in use"; exit 1} }' /etc/passwd
}


declare -i new_uid=''
while sleep .5; do
   read -rp "Enter a new uid: " new_uid;

   if valid_range $new_uid && unused $new_uid; then
      break     # exit once we get a valid unused uid
   fi
done
```

I'm only going to accept integers, I have a small built in sleep to keep it on a leash, I have error messages explaining what is going on, and it's fairly small and very easy to read.

Comment: Shouldn't `awk -F: -v u=$uid '$3 == u {print "Uid in use"; exit 1}' /etc/passwd` suffice?

Comment: @alvits, instead of the "if", yes it would.  It's just a different style.  Since almost every language uses an if block, I default to it.